# groovy: test an array in one line

Tags: arrays, groovy, if-statement

I want to test and see if everything in an array passes my check, here is how I am presently doing it and my fantasy code which crashes the compiler.

Current:

```
def mylist = [1,2,3,4]
def presumeTrue = true
mylist.each{
  if(it<0)presumeTrue=false
}
if(presumeTrue)println "Everything was greater than 0!!"
```

Fantasy:

```
def mylist = [1,2,3,4]
if(mylist*>0)println "Everything was greater than 0, but this sugar doesn't work."
```

Is there a correct way to apply an if test to everything in a list one one line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`every` method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#every%28groovy.lang.Closure%29):

```
myList.every { it > 0 }
```

The operator you were trying to use is "spread dot", which is `*.` (not `*`). You'd need to use the method name (`compareTo`), which takes an argument. But `map` isn't what you're trying to do.

You're not trying to apply the method to all of `mylist`'s members, you're trying to aggregate the result of applying the method to all the members, more like:

```
mylist.inject(true) { acc, n -> acc && n > 0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me...

```
def mylist = [1,2,3,4]
if(!mylist.find {it < 1}) println "Everything was greater than 0, and this sugar DID work."
```